# Two Way Binding in Xamarin.Forms custom control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, windows-10-universal

I created a custom control in Xamarin and it has a 2 way Bindable property.

```
public static BindableProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create<MultiSelectList, IEnumerable>(o => o.SelectedItems, default(IEnumerable), BindingMode.TwoWay,
                propertyChanged: OnSelectedItemsChanged);

        public IEnumerable SelectedItems
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
        }
```

but the binding works only from ViewModel to the control. if the property value changes in the control it is not getting reflected in the viewmodel property that is bound to this. Just to be sure I assign new Ienumerable object whenever the property value changes inside the custom control.
I am using Xamarin.Forms version 2.0.1.6505
Any help on how to force the binding from control to viewmodel?

Comment: Rajan, could you add more code about the viewmodel? and the xaml file if you are using this to add your custom control.

Comment: I spent sometime in that and kind of figured out what is the issue. it seems to be type conversion issue. SelectedItems property declared as IEnumerable in the user control. but the property bound to this from View Model is ReactiveList. so it works from View Model to the control since ReactiveList implements IEnumerable. but whenever the change occurre the user control creates List<object> which is not compatible with ReactiveList.
I tried to use IValueConverter but it goes into infinite loop at least in windows phone environment. not sure why it happens.

Comment: I am using generic so that you can provide the type of the SelectedItems when you instantiate the control like MultiSelect<ReactiveList<object>>.
I am not sure this is the best approach. any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ObservableCollection instead of IEnumerable. The ObservableCollection will refresh the UI when it changed, not IEnumerable.